# How to match road shape from polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm new to QGIS. How can I match road shape with polygon? I have example output I made using 'Join Attribute by location' but the result isn't something what I want (some roads exceeds the Area) I'm looking for like clean result, only the road within the Area. how do i achieve that?
Note from the dataset, there is 2 Type Line, Line A and B. my method was I'm joining the first line (Line A) with the Area. As a result I have the 'Joined Layer'. Then I want to join the 'Joined Layer' with the Line B. seems impractical but I don't know what's the best solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the feature "Extract/Clip by extent". And do not forget to check the option "Clip features to extent" to avoid the road from exceeding your polygon